# React Hooks .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and am having an issue trying to render my component.  It is a select component that will show a list of hospitals.  It uses an axios get request to obtain the data.  When trying to use the .map function, the console displays the "hospitals.map is not a function" error.

Here's the code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { FaSearch, FaArrowDown } from "react-icons/fa";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
    Container,
    Col,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    Button,
    Row,
} from "reactstrap";
import "./App.css";


function Hospitals( ){

    const [hospitals, setHospitals] = useState("")


    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchHospitals = async () => {
        const result = await axios(
        '/search',
        );
    
        setHospitals(result.data);
    };
    
    fetchHospitals();

    }, []);
    

    return (
        <Container className="formcontainer">
                <h2>
                    Pay Less for Healthcare Services! Start Here
                </h2>
                <Form className="form">
                    <Col>
                    <FormGroup>
                              <Input
                              type="select"
                              onChange = {e => setHospitals(e.target.value)}
                              value={hospitals}
                              >
                              {hospitals.map((hospital) =>
                                <option 
                                key={hospital.id}
                                value= {hospital.hospital_name}
                                > {hospital.hospital_name} </option>
                              )}
                              </Input>
                            </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Button>
                        Search <FaSearch />
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Container>
    )
}

export default Hospitals
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(result.data)` in your useEffect hook? Also you should probably move the `fetchHospitals` function declaration out of that hook.

Comment: `const [hospitals, setHospitals] = useState("")` - you've initially declared `hospitals` as an empty string, change it to an empty array `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .map() function only works for arrays.
So hospitals should be an array.
I think

```
const [hospitals, setHospitals] = useState([]);
```

will do it for you.